# Determine is a string is integer or double or plain string

Tags: java

Is there an efficient/clean way to determine if a `String` contains a sequence of chars that can be interpreted as: a) Integer b) Double c) If a or b don’t apply then it is an alphanumeric?

Comment: @Jim Integer.valueof(..), Double.valueOf(..)

Comment: @Jens:I know how to convert a string to an Integer or Double. I am asking how can I determine if a string contains a sequence that is a valid Integer or Double.

Comment: there are some options: NumberUtils.isNumber from Apache Commons, regex and a sequence of try parse and try another type.

Comment: If you mean "does the string contain _any numerical subsequence_", then that's as simple as "does the string contain any digit?" . A digit is `\\d` in regex.

Comment: @Khelwood:How does that show if it is a Double or Int?

Comment: @Jim If the string contains any digits then it contains a valid int and a valid double, depending on how you interpret it. If you want something else, you need to explain your question better. Give example input/output.

Comment: If you use only a regex, you may well establish that a string contains only digits but that doesn't mean it will fit into an Integer type.

Comment: @khelwood:If it is a valid Double it can't be assigned to an Integer. I want to distinguish if the sequence is numeric and if is a double or integer

Comment: @Jim how would you like a number like a 1 followed by 50 zeros to be classified? It is mathematically an integer, but Java can't represent it as an int. It can be represented as a BigInteger or a double.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou:The post is only about numbers that can be represented as Integer or Double

Comment: In that case, ByeBye's answer is the one that's applicable in your situation. If you don't want to degrade performance by throwing exceptions (or don't like using exceptions as control flow) then you can copy the Java API implementations of Integer.parseInt and Double.parseDouble, and replace `throw`s by `return`s.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You can use methods:

```
String text = "1000";
try {
    Integer.valueOf(text);
} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    System.out.println("not integer");
}
try {
    Double.valueOf(text);
} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    System.out.println("not double");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether you want to support locale or Not.

So you have 2 choices:

1. Don't use Locale

   - Just try Integer.parseInt and Double.parseDouble
2. Check for specific Locale/Language

   - Use Pattern to check Or NumberFormat

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your numbers are written in the usual programming language form (e.g. decimal separators are dots etc), you can try to use regular expressions:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Test {

  private static String typeOfThing(String text) {
    if (Pattern.matches("[+-]?[0-9]+", text)) {
      return "integer";
    } else if (Pattern.matches("[+-]?(([0-9]+\\.[0-9]+)|([0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?e[+-]?[0-9]+))", text)) {
      return "double";
    } else return "other";
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(typeOfThing("+123")); // integer
    System.out.println(typeOfThing("123"));  // integer
    System.out.println(typeOfThing("-123")); // integer
    System.out.println(typeOfThing("123.456")); // double
    System.out.println(typeOfThing("-1.123e-10")); // double
    System.out.println(typeOfThing("123hello")); // other
  }
}
```

The above is just a proof of concept, it touches on scientific notation but might be missing some edge cases (e.g. `NaN`s etc). Incidentally, Java's own decimal parser is pretty [intense](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/misc/FloatingDecimal.java#FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: You need to also allow a + in e.g. 123.456e+123.

Comment: Of course, what's not clear from the question is whether he's asking if a string is lexically an integer or double, or whether it can actually _fit_ into either of the Java types Integer or Double.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((variable == Math.floor(variable)) && !Double.isInfinite(variable)) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to know if the given string is an integer or not

Note: it will return true for bigintegers too

```
entered_string.matches("\\d+")
```

To know if the entered string is float try this

```
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+$");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(entered_string);
```

if you want to know if given string is just a string try this

```
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]*$");
  Matcher m = p.matches(entered_string);//as you requested for plain text
```